# How to create a subset from a dataframe based on changing exam status

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, subset

I would like to know how to create a subset from a dataframe in python, based on the changing of an exam status of a patient with a corresponding id (one id per patient)

For example, if a certain id has 5 exams (and exam_status can be 1 or 0) I would like to create a new dataframe based only on the patients that **changed** the exam status (from 0 to 1).The original df has 72 columns, so it's like a copy from the original but selecting only the ones where "exam_status" changed from 0 to 1

I know how to create a df based on the last exam_status:

```
    df = df.groupby("id").last()[list(df.groupby("id")["exam_status"].last() == 1)]
```

But I want the ones who changed! Can someone help?
Thank you!!

here's an example of an id that changed:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLamJ.png)

Comment: Can you provide a example dataset? (Input and matching expected output)

Comment: The input is a df with the columns exam_status and I'd, among many others that are exam variables. And the output I want is a dataframe that is a subset of the original, but only with the id's that changed exam status from 0 to 1. Basically grouped by id

Comment: I meant an actual text example, not a description.